# Given a boolean matrix $M$ what are the matrices formed by replacing $1s$ in $M$ with $0s$ called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, order-theory, boolean-ring

Given two boolean matrices $A$ and $B$ over some common dimensions one can form an order via $A\leq B\iff \forall i,j(A_{i,j}\leq B_{i,j})$ under this order, what would the matrix $A$ be called in reference to $B$? Would it be okay to say "$A$ is less then or equal to $B$", when using only logical matrices?

Or does this order have a specific name (for instance might I say "$A$ is a cousin of $B$" or something like "$A$ is component wise less then or equal to $B$" (under the $\land$/$\lor$ lattice)?

Equivalently this is the partial order labeled $U$ found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix#Lattice

Comment: *less than or equal to*; or *at most*; or *under* probably all work fine. The question in the heading would just be *complement* or *(pointwise) complement*. Exercise: The matrices over a lattice *L* is again a lattice ;-) ---everything is done pointwise